# command to generate a \cite{} only on first use

Tags: bibtex, natbib, conditionals

In a book dealing with R, I use a command `\pkg{}` for every mention of an R package, that also generates index extries via another command `\ixp{}`.

```
\newcommand{\pkg}[1]{\textsf{#1}\ixp{#1}}
```

All packages have .bib entries, and I'd like to modify this so that the package is also `\cite{}`d in the text on its **first** use, but thereafter generates a `\nocite{}`. That is, something like

```
\newcommand{\pkg}[1]{\textsf{#1}\ixp{#1} \citep{#1}}
```

but where `\citep{#1}` becomes `\nocite{#1}` if the .bib key argument (`#1`) has occurred before in the text. (As I recall, glossary packages do something like this.)  How can I modify this definition to achieve this behavior?

The goal here is to also generate the references for all packages, but avoid cluttering the text with a citation for each mention.  Using `\nocite{}` after the first occurrence is desired for the purpose of generating entries in an Author index.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[comma]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Subject Index,columns=2]

% Cited packages

\newcommand{\Rpackage}[1]{\pkg{#1} package}
%\newcommand{\pkg}[1]{\textsf{#1}\ixp{#1}}
\newcommand{\pkg}[1]{\textsf{#1}\ixp{#1} \citep{#1}}

% R packages:  indexed under both package name and packages!
\newcommand{\ixp}[1]{%
   \index{#1@\textsf{#1} package}%
   \index{package!#1@\textsf{#1}}%
    }

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@Manual{vcd,
  title =        "vcd: Visualizing Categorical Data",
  author =       "David Meyer and Achim Zeileis and Kurt Hornik",
  year =         "2015",
  note =         "R package version 1.3-3",
}

@Manual{vcdExtra,
  title =        "vcdExtra: vcd Extensions and Additions",
  author =       "Michael Friendly",
  year =         "2015",
  note =         "R package version 0.6-7",
  URL =          "http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=vcdExtra",
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
Here we mention the \pkg{vcd} package and \pkg{vcdExtra}.  
% Should generate a \citep{vcd} and \citep{vcdExtra} 

\section{First section}
Here we mention the \pkg{vcd} package and \pkg{vcdExtra} again.
These should generate nocite instead.
% Should generate a \nocite{vcd} and \nocite{vcdExtra} 

\chapter{Second chapter}
Here we mention the \pkg{vcd} package and \pkg{vcdExtra} again
These should generate nocite instead.
% Should generate a \nocite{vcd} and \nocite{vcdExtra} 

\section{First section}
asfdAFASFAF

\bibliography{references}
\printindex

\end{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You could use a bool, cite if bool=true and set the bool false within the macro. It will set the bool false every time, but who cares? You can also *restore* (bool->true) with the beginning of a chapter.

Comment: within the `\newcommand` definition, you could redefine the command at the end with a `\renewcommand` to reset for all uses after the first.  this isn't reversible, unlike a boolean.

Comment: it's not really clear to me why `\nocite` is needed.  once an item is cited, there's an entry in the `.aux` file to make sure the item is pulled from the `.bib` into the `.bbl` file; that needs to happen only once.  you may have another reason for `\nocite`, but i'm curious -- what is it?

Comment: There will be an Author Index, generated with the `authorindex` package.  My hope is that `\nocite{}` could then trigger the appropriate entries there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you need this:

```
\def\pkg#1{\textsf{#1}\ixp{#1}~\citex{#1}}
\def\citex#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname cit:#1\endcsname\relax
      \expandafter\gdef\csname cit:#1\endcsname{}%
      \citep{#1}%
   \else
      \nocite{#1}%
   \fi
}
```

The `\citex` macro tests if the parameter was used before, i.e. if the control sequence `\cit:parameter` is defined. If not, then it expands to `\citep{parameter}` and defines `\cit:parameter`. Else it expands to `\nocite{parameter}`.

Answer (score 2):

I added a `*`-variant that prints the citation anyway, and it doesn't count as the first (maybe you want it in the introduction or later in the document).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Manual{vcd,
  title =        "vcd: Visualizing Categorical Data",
  author =       "David Meyer and Achim Zeileis and Kurt Hornik",
  year =         "2015",
  note =         "R package version 1.3-3",
}

@Manual{vcdExtra,
  title =        "{vcdExtra}: vcd Extensions and Additions",
  author =       "Michael Friendly",
  year =         "2015",
  note =         "R package version 0.6-7",
  URL =          "http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=vcdExtra",
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[comma]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Subject Index,columns=2]

% Cited packages

\newcommand{\Rpackage}[1]{\pkg{#1} package}
%\newcommand{\pkg}[1]{\textsf{#1}\ixp{#1}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\pkg}{%
  \@ifstar{\@tempswatrue\pkg@do}{\@tempswafalse\pkg@do}%
}
\newcommand\pkg@do[1]{%
  % fixed part
  \textsf{#1}\ixp{#1}%
  \if@tempswa
    \space\citep{#1}%
  \else
    \ifcsname pkg@cited@#1\endcsname
      %\nocite{#1}% uncomment, if you want, but it does nothing
    \else
      \space\citep{#1}%
      \global\expandafter\let\csname pkg@cited@#1\endcsname\@empty
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% R packages:  indexed under both package name and packages!
\newcommand{\ixp}[1]{%
   \index{#1@\textsf{#1} package}%
   \index{package!#1@\textsf{#1}}%
    }

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
Here we mention the \pkg{vcd} package and \pkg{vcdExtra}.  
% Should generate a \citep{vcd} and \citep{vcdExtra} 

\section{First section}
Here we mention the \pkg{vcd} package and \pkg{vcdExtra} again.
These should generate nocite instead.
% Should generate a \nocite{vcd} and \nocite{vcdExtra} 

But we want to cite \pkg*{vcd} again.

\chapter{Second chapter}
Here we mention the \pkg{vcd} package and \pkg{vcdExtra} again
These should generate nocite instead.
% Should generate a \nocite{vcd} and \nocite{vcdExtra} 

\section{First section}
asfdAFASFAF

\bibliography{\jobname}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

on the assumption that `\nocite` isn't really needed, this should work:

```
\newcommand{\expkg|[1]{\textsf{#1}\ixp{#1}}
\newcommand{\pkg}[1]{\textsf{#1}\ixp{#1} \citep{#1}\expkg{#1}}
```

after all, a single `\cite` will put an entry in the `\.aux` file that tells
bibtex to identify a matching entry in the `.bib` file and create an equivalent
entry in the `.bbl` file -- only one is needed.  the usual purpose of `\nocite`
is to ensure that an item is included in the `.bbl` file (thus in the bibliography)
if it is *not* actually cited in the text.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but perhaps you would find it useful. Here is a package I wrote, but never published to serve a similar but not identical purpose. The purpose of this package is to make it easier to write articles on programming languages. To reference a language such as Java, you write `\Java` in your input. It would add the citation, but only if this is the first use of the command.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{yogi-lang}[2005/09/12 v0.6]
\DeclareOption{terse}{\relax}
\DeclareOption{verbose}{\relax}
\ProcessOptions

\RequirePackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\@pl}[1]{\mbox{\textsc{\ensureLR{#1}}}\xspace}
\newcommand\lang[1]{\@pl{#1}}

\newcommand\NonCitingUseX[1]{\csname nocite#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\NonCitingUse[1]{\NonCitingUseX{#1}\xspace}
\newcommand\@IgnoreLanguageCitation[1]{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname{\csname nocite#1\endcsname}%
}
\newcommand\StopLanguageCitation[1]{%
\expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname{\csname nocite#1\endcsname\xspace}%
}


\def\@LANG#1#2#3{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname nocite#1\endcsname{#3}% Define the base version, as e.g., \nociteJava
    \expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname{% First time invocation.
        \NonCitingUseX{#1}\relax      % Invoke the base version.
        \StopLanguageCitation{#1}\relax % Reset the definition for all future uses.
         ~#2\relax                    % Append the citation.
        \xspace
    }%
    \xspace
}

\newcommand\NewLanguageCitation[2]{\@LANG{#1}{\textup{#2}}{\textsc{#1}}}
\newcommand\NewLangaugeCitationSpecial[3]{\@LANG{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\DeclareOption{terse}{%
\gdef\@LANG#1#2#3{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname nocite#1\endcsname{#3}% Define the base version, as e.g., \nociteJava
    \expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname{% First time invocation.
        \NonCitingUseX{#1}\relax      % Invoke the base version.
        \StopLanguageCitation{#1}\relax % Reset the definition for all future uses.
        %~#2\relax                    % Append the citation.
        \xspace
    }%
   \xspace
}}

\ProcessOptions
\def\STOPLANGUAGECITATION{\def\langcite##1{}}
\def\STARTLANGUAGECITATION{\def\langcite##1{\cite{##1}}}
\STARTLANGUAGECITATION
%Use alphabetical ordering
\NewLanguageCitation{Go}{\langcite{XXX}}
\NewLangaugeCitationSpecial{AJEE}{\langcite{Cohen:Gil:04}}{\textsc{AspectJ2EE}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Ada}{\langcite{Tucker:97}}
\NewLanguageCitation{BCPL}{\langcite{Richards:Whitby-Strevens:80}}
\NewLanguageCitation{AspectJ}{\langcite{Kiczales:2001}}
\NewLanguageCitation{AWK}{\langcite{Aho:Kernighan:Weinberger:Book:88}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Basic}{}
\NewLanguageCitation{CPL}{\langcite{Kernighan:Ritchie:Book:88}}
\NewLangaugeCitationSpecial{CC}{\langcite{Stroustrup:Book:97}}{\mbox{C++}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Cecil}{\langcite{Chambers:Cecil:93}}
\NewLanguageCitation{CLOS}{\langcite{CLOS}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Cobol}{}
\NewLanguageCitation{CommonLoops}{\langcite{Bobrow:Kahn:Kiczales:Masinter:Stefik:Zdybel:86}}
\NewLangaugeCitationSpecial{CProlog}{\langcite{Shapiro:87}}{\textsc{Concurrent Prolog}}
\NewLangaugeCitationSpecial{CSharp}{\langcite{Hejlsberg:Wiltamuth:Golde:03}}{\textsc{C}${}^{\#}$}
\NewLanguageCitation{Datalog}{\langcite{Ceri:Gottlob:Tanca:90}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Dylan}{\langcite{Dylan:Shalit:97}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Eiffel}{\langcite{Eiffel:Reference:97}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Fickle}{\langcite{Drossopoulou:Damiani:Ciancaglini:Giannini:01}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Flavors}{\langcite{Moon:Flavors:86}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Fortran}{}
\NewLanguageCitation{Haskell}{\langcite{Jones:03}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Jam}{\langcite{Ancona:Lagorio:Zucca:03}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Java}{\langcite{Arnold:Gosling:96}}
\NewLanguageCitation{JavaScript}{\langcite{Flanagan:11}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Kea}{\langcite{Kea}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Lisp}{\langcite{Graham:95}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Mathematica}{\langcite{mangano:10}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Mesa}{}
\NewLanguageCitation{MixGen}{\langcite{Allen:Bannet:Cartwright:03}}
\NewLanguageCitation{ML}{\langcite{ml-spec:Milner:Tofte:Harper:MacQueen:97}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Modula}{\langcite{Nelson:91}}
\NewLanguageCitation{NextGen}{\langcite{Allen:Bannet:Cartwright:03}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Oberon}{\langcite{Wirth:Reiser:Book:92}}
\NewLanguageCitation{ObjectiveC}{\langcite{Cox:Book:Evolutionary:86}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Pascal}{\langcite{Wirth:71}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Perl}{\langcite{Perl:94}}
\NewLanguageCitation{PHP}{\langcite{Lerdorf:Tatroe:02}}
\NewLangaugeCitationSpecial{PLI}{\langcite{Hughes:86}}{\textsc{PL/1}}
\NewLanguageCitation{PolyGlot}{\langcite{PolyGlot}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Prolog}{\langcite{Deransart:Cervoni:Ed-Dbali:96}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Python}{\langcite{Lutz:96}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Ruby}{\langcite{Thomas:Hunt:00}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Scala}{\langcite{Odersky:Altherr:Cremet:Emir:Maneth:Micheloud:Mihaylov:Schinz:Stenman:Zenger:04}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Scheme}{\langcite{Dickey:92}}
\NewLanguageCitation{SED}{\langcite{ref:sed}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Self}{\langcite{Ungar:Smith:87}}
\NewLanguageCitation{Smalltalk}{\langcite{Goldberg:Book:84}}
\NewLanguageCitation{SQL}{}
\NewLanguageCitation{Tcl}{\langcite{Ousterhout:90}}
\NewLangaugeCitationSpecial{THETA}{\langcite{Liskov:al:95}}{\lang{Theta}}
\NewLanguageCitation{XQuery}{\langcite{XQuery}}
\NewLanguageCitation{APL}{\langcite{Iverson:62}}
```